# LaTeX - tabular start at new line

Tags: latex, tabular

I want to start the tabular at start of line, but when I put it directly after e.g. `\paragraph{Foo}`, than It will be displayed at right side of 'Foo'.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4,titlepage]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\paragraph{A}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{B}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled LaTeX sample]

I know, I could put it between `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`, but than it would float around (i.e. will sometimes be displayed after the following text) and will be centered, which looks strange for small tables.

I strongly believe that this question is already answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just so you know, there is a [Tex and Latex Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). Remember though: [don't post an exact copy of your question there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/1081494), but it is worth noting in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the table to start in a new line like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4,titlepage]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\paragraph{A}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{B}\mbox{}\par
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc}
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
X & Y & Z \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]